Implementation of permutation in PRESENT cipher algorithm
I have implemented up to the substitution step for each round in my PRESENT cipher algorithm with python language and now stuck at the next step which is permutation. Suppose I have a 64-bit data in binary representation (say for example '1001010001100010000001010100100110100100001100110110001101010000'. Now the thing I want for this data is to be permuted according to the permutation process as shown in the given image. How can I build the logic to achieve that? Please also share the reverse process to be able to decode the encrypted data.
Any suggestions or ideas will be appreciated.


There are many ways. For example, you can number the bits from 0 to 63, and then have a list bit_perm where bit_perm[i] tells which output bit position the bit in input bit position i maps to. If I understand the image correctly, if we number the bits starting with 0 at the left, bit_perm[0] = 0 and bit_perm[1] = 16, and so on.

You must have come to a solution to this by now. Here is how I performed the permutation for the Present Cipher.
The permutation is stored as a list, where each input bit is mapped to
the output bits.
permutation = [0,16,32,48,1,17,33,49,2,18,34,50,3,19,35,51,4,
           20,36,52,5,21,37,53,6,22,38,54,7,23,39,55,8,24,
           40,56,9,25,41,57,10,26,42,58,11,27,43,59,12,28,
           44,60,13,29,45,61,14,30,46,62,15,31,47,63]

def pLayer(data):
    """
    data is 64-bit hex
    """
    original_data = list(format(data, '#066b')[2:])
    permuted_data = list(format(data, '#066b')[2:])
    for i, j in enumerate(permutation):
        permuted_data[j] = original_data[I]
    return int("0b" + "".join(permuted_data), 2)

The code list(format(data, '#066b')[2:]) converts the hexadecimal number to a Python list of ones and zeros in string, making it easier for substitution and permutation.
Usage:
>>> a = 0xcccccccccccccccc
>>> permuted_a = pLayer(a)
>>> hex(permuted_a)
'0xffffffff00000000'

You can view my full implementation here.
I have also discussed the details of the Present cipher in my blog.
Hoping this helps :).
